# IBS Chinese pinyin input candidates appear at bottom of screen

Tags: keyboard, language-support, input-language, chinese, pinyin

So I got ibs pinyin working on Ubuntu, but the input candidates appear at the bottom of my screen not near the cursor where they're supposed to.

This is quite annoying as you gotta look in two places on the screen at once: eg. if i'm typing in my browser's address bar.

Comment: Can it possibly be changed in the Preferences window? `/usr/lib/ibus/ibus-setup-pinyin`

Comment: i don't know which line to change. besides the commented text regarding to copyright all I see in this:
`prefix=/usr

exec_prefix=${prefix}
datarootdir=${prefix}/share
export IBUS_PREFIX=/usr
export IBUS_DATAROOTDIR=${prefix}/share
export IBUS_LOCALEDIR=${datarootdir}/locale
cd /usr/share/ibus-pinyin/setup/
exec python main.py $@`

Comment: Running that in terminal opens a GUI for me.

Comment: oh, didn't open it in terminal. yeah, the only option there is orientation of candidates horizontal or vertical. tried changing that but it is just displayed horizontally or vertically at bottom of the screen and not near the caret position

Comment: Ok, then I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the ibus pinyin candidate appear at bottom of some application, You need to install extra packet, which I think is ibus-gtk.

Synaptic Package Manager -> search for ibus -> Mark recommended for installation -> install ibus-gtk and log out.

Comment: i think that actually worked.

Comment: I confirm this works. It would be even better if it would appear directly below where you are typing.

Comment: Installing ibus-* achieves what I wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by installing the `ibus-gtk3` package, logging out and then logging in again. I'm using Linux Mint 17.3, but this should work on any other distros. No need to install all of the ibus-* packages.