# The iBus candidate window appears at the bottom of WPS Office

Tags: xubuntu, ibus, wps-office

I have a small problem with [WPS Office](http://wps-community.org/). The iBus input method's candidate window appears at the bottom of the window instead of following the cursor as it's supposed to do. Here is [the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtrPQ.png) to the image. I read [this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549900/ibs-chinese-pinyin-input-candidates-appear-at-bottom-of-screen) and tried reinstalling iBus completely, but that didn't work. The strange thing is that the candidate window appears and works completely fine in LibreOffice, but not in WPS Office. Is this a bug in WPS Office, or is this something I could fix on my system. By the way, I'm using Xubuntu 14.04 LTS, my iBus version is 1.5.5, and my WPS Office version is 10.1.05460. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to install Google Pinyin using the [Fcitx Input Method](https://fcitx-im.org/wiki/Fcitx). The input method candidate window appears right next to the text when typing. Here is how you can install Google Pinyin and Fcitx:

1. Run `sudo apt-get install fcitx-googlepinyin` in the terminal. You will need to provide an administrative password.
2. Then run `im-config`. Click OK, and click "Yes" to update your user configuration and select Fcitx as the user configuration.
3. Restart your computer and click the keyboard icon located at the top right corner of the system panel.
4. Click on "Configure Current Input Method". In the new window, press the + icon to add a new language. De-select “Only show current language” and type "Google-Pinyin". Then click "OK".
5. Switch between Google Pinyin and your default language by pressing Ctrl+Space.